# I have some MDX Code that I cannot understand

Tags: mdx-query

I have found this code below, works just fine in the variant of MDX that I'm using ( Cognos TM1 ), but I can't seem to understand how it works.

what value is name give to be able to be compared to the character "}"

[}Dimensions].CurrentMember.Name < "}" )}

This particular query filters out the names that start with "}" as these are control objects. e.g.  }ABCD

Answer (score 0):

Buddy answered for me today;

That's a string comparison, so would use the ascii character order to compare the 2 strings.

It compares one character at a time, left to right -- it doesn't add them up.

The leftmost character is most significant, so for example:

```
BBB > AAA
BAA > ABB
AAB > AAA
ABA > AAC
BAA > ACC
```

The number of characters compared = the length of the shortest string, so in your example, it's just comparing the first character.